# Refresh updatepanel inside masterpage from content

Tags: c#, updatepanel, master-pages

I have a label kept inside an update panel in my masterpage. I will set the a number at code behind that will be display in the label. Assuming now the text of the label is 50.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="remarks" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
                            Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Red" Width="28px"></asp:Label>  
       </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

then at its content page, there will be a gridview. once i select the gridview, the number of the label at masterpage will be decrease by one. (example number will now be 49)

However the number will only decrease if I select the gridview PLUS refresh the whole page. if there anyway when i select the gridview it will only refresh the update panel inside the masterpage without having the refresh the whole web page?

Answer (score 0):

You can try javascript or jQuery for updating Label text

check this out :
http://encosia.com/easily-refresh-an-updatepanel-using-javascript/

[Update an UpdatePanel manually using JavaScript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490457/update-an-updatepanel-manually-using-javascript-or-jquery)