# Refresh partial parent page on closing popup in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

On click of button a popup window open. In the child window I made some changes and when I save, popup need to be closed and partial parent page refreshed like a single updatepanel.

I don’t want complete parent page refresh.

Comment: Why can't you [use the updatepanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490457/update-an-updatepanel-manually-using-javascript-or-jquery)?

Comment: In parent page 3 updatepanels are present.I want to update only one

Comment: Have you took a look at the link I posted?

Comment: One more question, button which refresh the parent panel is inside masterpage .So how i can mange this in .getElementById

Comment: hey thanx a lot i solved it by making clientIdmode=static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to trigger the event that refreshes the target update panel from the popup.  One way of doing this is using the window.opener element.

Here is a simple example of code in a popup that you can adapt for your project.  Note you'll need to change 'btnTriggersUpdate' to the ClientID that is given to whatever Button triggers the Update Panel refresh.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnRefreshParentUpdatePanel" OnClientClick="window.opener.document.getElementById('btnTriggersUpdate').click();" Text="Refresh Parent Update Panel" />
```

In my example, here is the Update Panel in the parent:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnTarget" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label id="lblUpdatePanelLabel" runat="server" Text="Not Updated"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="btnTriggersUpdate" runat="server" Text="Refreshes Update Panel" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Parent's btnTriggerUpdate_Click to prove it updates:

```
Protected Sub btnTriggersUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTriggersUpdate.Click
    lblUpdatePanelLabel.Text = "Updated"
End Sub
```